# How to re-mint NFTs to the existing holders?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

Suppose, I've created an NFT collection of V1, of ERC751 or ERC1155. After some time, I've discovered that I want to fix a bug or improve it in some way, and this will become V2.

- I'll then go ahead to re-mint NFTs of V2 to all the existing holders of V1, right?
- How will I, as the developer of the NFTs, find out who the existing holders are?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146583/discussion-on-question-by-dankenn-how-to-re-mint-nfts-to-the-existing-holders); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.